# SQL Statement to Update Rows using ids from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert

and thanks in advance. I have a table called users which contains an id. I would like to collect the ids only from that table and run and insert using those ids as one of the arguments. I am new to SQL and having some trouble finding help or a solution.
Here is the statement to get the ids
`SELECT id FROM public.users`With the ids that are returned I would like to run an insert or update resembling `insert into public.history (user_id, password, change_time) values (<ids from prev SELECT>, 'password', now());`
Can I generate a loop? Could someone point me in the right direction using purely sql, I know this can be achieved in php but I'd like to include this in an db init with SQL only.

Comment: Yes you can but how you do it depends on what database you using, is it mssql, mysql etc. Please specify.

Comment: This is a mysql db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO public.history (user_id, password, change_time) 
SELECT id, 'password', now() 
FROM public.users
```

Comment: Let me attempt to explain what this feature is. Upon creation of a user, I need to reset their password history. This is why I want to run the INSERT, as it resets the history. I need to grab the user ids from the public users table. And pass them into the INSERT table.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question. If you have another requirement then you can ask a new question.